# Java JavaMail compile error

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, email

I would like know there are any mistakes in the code because it does not run. It also shows an error on the line that I have labelled below.

```
  String to = email;

  // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
  String from = "dummy@gmail.com";

  // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
  String host = "localhost";

  // Get system properties
  Properties properties = System.getProperties();

  // Setup mail server
  properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

  // Get the default Session object.
  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

  try{
     // Create a default MimeMessage object.
     MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

     // Set From: header field of the header.
     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

     // Set To: header field of the header.
     message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));  //The error is here : it says Message is internal propitiatory API and may be removed in future release 

     // Set Subject: header field
     message.setSubject("Student Report");

     // Now set the actual message
     message.setText("Greeting Sir/Madam, Your son/daughter has been absent for more than 20%. Please be adviced");

     // Send message
     Transport.send(message);
     System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
  }catch (MessagingException mex) {
     mex.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: Have a look at your imports, looks like your IDE picked up a wrong package containing a class called Message.  You need `javax.mail.Message`

Comment: Try changing 
`message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, ...`
to
`message.addRecipient(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, ...`